# Add metadata while converting MKV to MP3 with FFMPEG

Tags: batch-file, audio, ffmpeg, metadata, mp3

I am trying to convert MKV files to MP3, while adding metadata and album artwork through a batch file. I am generating a PNG through FFMPEG, then converting to MP3 while adding metadata, and finally adding the album artwork i got initially.

I have tried adding the metadata while converting to MP3 and while adding the artwork to no avail. I read something about it flushing the buffer too quickly but thought I might be able to get around it by adding it while converting it.

Individually, all parts work, but I can't get it to add the title and artist to the metadata, or at least in a place where VLC can read it. any suggestions?

```
@echo off
::Extracts a PNG thumbnail 
for %%A in ("*.mkv") do (ffmpeg -ss 30 -i "%%A" -qscale:v 4 -frames:v 1 "%%~nA.png")

::Convert from MKV to MP3 and adds title and artist based on file name delimited by "-" eg Metallica - Enter Sandman.mkv
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%A in ("*.mkv") do (
    set filename=%%~nA
    set artist=
    set song=
    echo "!filename!"

    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%G in ("!filename!") do (
        set artist="%%G"
        set song="%%H"
        echo !artist!
        echo !song!
    )

    echo !song! by !artist!

    ffmpeg -i "%%A" -b:a 192K -id3v2_version 4 -write_id3v2 1 -metadata title="%song%" -metadata artist="%artist%" -flush_packets 0 -vn "%%~nA.mp3"
)

::Add Artwork to MP3
for %%A in ("*.mp3") do (ffmpeg -i "%%A" -i "%%~nA.png" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 "UPDATED%%~nA.mp3")
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted those doublequotes and leading/trailing spaces, because for e.g. `Metallica - Enter Sandman.mkv`, your command parameters will include this substring `-metadata title="" Enter Sandman"" -metadata artist=""Metallica ""`.

Comment: I did recognize that and added a :Trim function, but didn't add it here to cut down on confusion. I'm considering recreating this in Python because I am starting to think this is a bit much for just a batch file to handle.

Comment: A trim function doesn't remove all of those doublequotes, only the leading and trailing space characters. In order to assist you we need to use the same code you're using, not just something you've made up to stop batch script experts from getting confused! Please post the actual code you need assistance with.

Comment: Sorry about that. I see what you mean now. I don't know what you mean by removing the double quotes. I thought I needed to use them to make sure they took the entire variable as they can have spaces in them. Would I be removing it from where I am setting the artist and song variables? `"%%G"` to just `%%G` and `"%%H"` to `%%H`? To clarify, this is exactly the code I am running currently though. I removed the :Trim to simplify the core issue. I'll probably add it back later and solve any issues with that once I actually get values being add to the metadata.

Comment: Just change `set artist="%%G"` to `set "artist=%%~G"` and `set song="%%H"` to `set "song=%%~H"`. You can then leave `-metadata title="%song%" -metadata artist="%artist%"` as it is.

Comment: I see. The double quotes were being concatenated with the variable when I set it. That makes sense to me now.